# How to make a background service to capture commands and their output?

Tags: centos, command-line, background-process

Is there anyway to make a background service capture all the commands executed by a user and also save the output in a text file?

Comment: There is e.g. `auditd` which can monitor your system, but recoding the outputs of all commands is difficult. Why do you need this? See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/linux-command-logging

Comment: There's the [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/script.1.html) command to log a terminal session to a file.

Comment: Thanx @glennjackman that is exactly what i needed!!